# Best database and database design for this particular need?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm looking to store around 50-100 million documents in a database and be able to do queries at a very fast speed. A document would look something like this:

```js
{
  name: 'example',
  value: '300,201,512'
}
```

The `value` column is always unique, `name` is not.
Now I want to be able to only check if there exists a document with a specific value using a query. What database would be the best choice and which design would be best to approach the fastest speed for a query like that?

Comment: Sorry to say but *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Answer (score 1):

NoSQL databases try to offer certain functionality that more traditional relational database management systems do not. Whether it is for holding simple key-value pairs for shorter lengths of time for caching purposes, or keeping unstructured collections (e.g. collections) of data that could not be easily dealt with using relational databases and the structured query language (SQL) – they are here to help.

In order to better understand the roles and underlying technology of each database management system, let's quickly go over these four operational models.

**Key / Value Based**

We will begin our NoSQL modeling journey with key / value based database management simply because they can be considered the most basic and backbone implementation of NoSQL.

These type of databases work by matching keys with values, similar to a dictionary. There is no structure nor relation. After connecting to the database server (e.g. Redis), an application can state a key (e.g. the_answer_to_life) and provide a matching value (e.g. 42) which can later be retrieved the same way by supplying the key.

Key / value DBMSs are usually used for quickly storing basic information, and sometimes not-so-basic ones after performing, for example, a CPU and memory intensive computation. They are extremely performant, efficient and usually easily scalable.

Note: When it comes to computers, a dictionary usually refers to a special sort of data object. They constitutes of arrays of collections with individual keys matching values.

**Column Based**

Column based NoSQL database management systems work by advancing the simple nature of key / value based ones.

Despite their complicated-to-understand image on the internet, these databases work very simply by creating collections of one or more key / value pairs that match a record.

Unlike the traditional defines schemas of relational databases, column-based NoSQL solutions do not require a pre-structured table to work with the data. Each record comes with one or more columns containing the information and each column of each record can be different.

Basically, column-based NoSQL databases are two dimensional arrays whereby each key (i.e. row / record) has one or more key / value pairs attached to it and these management systems allow very large and un-structured data to be kept and used (e.g. a record with tons of information).

These databases are commonly used when simple key / value pairs are not enough, and storing very large numbers of records with very large numbers of information is a must. DBMS implementing column-based, schema-less models can scale extremely well.

**Document Based**

Document based NoSQL database management systems can be considered the latest craze that managed to take a lot of people by storm. These DBMS work in a similar fashion to column-based ones; however, they allow much deeper nesting and complex structures to be achieved (e.g. a document, within a document, within a document).

Documents overcome the constraints of one or two level of key / value nesting of columnar databases. Basically, any complex and arbitrary structure can form a document, which can be stored using these management systems.

Despite their powerful nature, and the ability to query records by individual keys, document based management systems have their own issues and downfalls compared to others. For example, retrieving a value of a record means getting the whole lot of it and same goes for updates, all of which affect the performance.

**Graph Based**

Finally, the very interesting flavour of NoSQL database management systems is the graph based ones.

The graph based DBMS models represent the data in a completely different way than the previous three models. They use tree-like structures (i.e. graphs) with nodes and edges connecting each other through relations.

Similarly to mathematics, certain operations are much simpler to perform using these type of models thanks to their nature of linking and grouping related pieces of information (e.g. connected people).

These databases are commonly used by applications whereby clear boundaries for connections are necessary to establish. For example, when you register to a social network of any sort, your friends' connection to you and their friends' friends' relation to you are much easier to work with using graph-based database management systems.

***Fasted document based db***

1) MongoDB

2) DynamoDB

[Here is difference for your reference](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Amazon+DynamoDB%3BMongoDB)

**I will give preference to DynamoDB**

> Currently, we are working on aws datalake, really fast performance
>   store data in [s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and get back via [athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import data on to some database then try using MS SQL Server 2008 R2, because it is very user friendly and allow you to do your work more accurately and precisely. If you want to do that without any cost, then MySQL will be a better option to do so(better MySQL editor is SQLYog). I hope it would be beneficial for you.

Comment: The data will be static and there will be no further imports after the table has been filled, so I wouldn't worry too much about user friendly. All I need is the fastest speed possible for the query I explained in the post. Also I'm looking to host the database locally so costs won't be a problem.

Comment: can you specify the size of the data?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: 
I think, 100 million documents in **your mentioned structure and conditions** is not **BIG ENOUGH** to use NoSQL. You can handle them with PostgreSQL and MySQL and etc.

Note that: for a long time Wikipedia used MySQL (not now). see [Reference](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Wikipedia-use-MySQL-as-a-data-store-rather-than-a-NoSQL-database-since-it-scales-and-will-be-economic)